# Navigating through Data Sheet with Specific Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that was used here "Navigation Arrow Macros
Section" -> https://www.contextures.com/xlForm02.html

```
Sub ViewLogFirst()
  
    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim InputWks As Worksheet

    Dim lRec As Long
    Dim lRecRow As Long
    Dim lLastRec As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set InputWks = Worksheets("visibleSheet")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("dataSheet")

    With InputWks
        .Range("CurrRec").Value = 1
        lRec = .Range("CurrRec").Value
        lRecRow = lRec + 1
        Range("A2").Value = historyWks.Cells(lRecRow, 1)
        Range("A3").Value = historyWks.Cells(lRecRow, 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

This basically will look through all the values in dataSheet, how can I add more criteria that will allow me to navigate through rows that have value "x" at a specific column?
For example, I want to navigate as the code was intended but only when the dataSheet has rows that contain "Test" in col no 5.

Any assistance?

Comment: Did you add the `Range("A2").Value` lines yourself? Because they are not qualified using your `With` statement. If you intended for that, put a period before them like the other `.Range` has. Without the period, it assumes `ActiveSheet` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: No, it was written in the original code and it works flawlessly. but it shows everything. 

I want to add a mini-filter to the navigation process, to navigate through rows that have specific value in x column.  so instead of navigating through everything I have in the data sheet (for example, 100 rows), it should navigate through (15 rows) that meet the criteria (for example: historyWks.Cells(lRecRow, 5) = "Test")

Comment: As you can see, code does not format well in comments. Instead, add that to your question. (Edit your question)